# Advice only applies in all cases after function calling advised function is re-evaluated

Tags: emacs, elisp

In my .emacs file, I have:

```
(defadvice narrow-to-region (around test activate)
   (message "advice")
   ad-do-it)
```

When I call narrow-to-region, the advice runs and prints 'advice' before narrowing.

When I call narrow-to-defun, it does not.

I found where narrow-to-defun is defined - in lisp.el, and re-evaluated the function.  At this point, the advice started running.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, apparently, due to byte-compilation and therefore the inability to advise the narrowing primitives (`narrow-to-region` is the primitive, `narrow-to-defun` calls `narrow-to-region`).

The following post on [Null Program](http://nullprogram.com/) (["The Limits of Emacs Advice"](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2013/01/22/)) goes into detail about this problem.  Here's the shortish version from deep in the post:

> It turns out `narrow-to-region` is so special -- probably because it's used very frequently -- that it gets its own bytecode. The primitive function call is being compiled away into a single instruction. This means my advice will not be considered in byte-compiled code. Darnit. The same is true for `widen` (code 126).

As to why the advice started working after you re-evaluated `narrow-to-defun`: I'm guessing it's because you ended up replacing the byte-compiled version when you re-evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

@Dan described the problem well.  Here is some info that might help you work around it.

What you can do is to advise (or to redefine) also `narrow-to-defun` (and perhaps `narrow-to-page`), so it acts similarly.

FWIW, I do something similar in library [`wide-n.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/wide-n.el) (see [Multiple Narrowings](http://www.emacswiki.org/MultipleNarrowings)).

I advise `narrow-to-region`.  But I also redefine `narrow-to-defun` and `narrow-to-page`.  In all 3 cases I make the same change, to record the details of each narrowing so you can return to them later.  Here is the advice, for example:

```
 (defadvice narrow-to-region (before push-wide-n-restrictions activate)
   "Push the region limits to `wide-n-restrictions'.
 You can use `C-x n x...' to widen to previous buffer restrictions."
   (when (or (interactive-p) wide-n-push-anyway-p)
     (wide-n-push (ad-get-arg 0) (ad-get-arg 1)))) ; Args START and END.
```

And here is the relevant part of the `narrow-to-defun` redefinition:

```
  ...
  (goto-char end)
  (re-search-backward "^\n" (- (point) 1) t)
  (when (or (interactive-p)  wide-n-push-anyway-p) (wide-n-push beg end)) ; <=====
  (narrow-to-region beg end))))
```

Comment: That's a nice library!  I'd been hoping to find that kind of functionality for a while.

Comment: @Dan: FWIW, it becomes even nicer when used with [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles). Multi-command `icicle-wide-n` lets you trip among the narrowings (and no narrowing) by name (completion) or cycling. And you can delete restrictions on the fly.